# Changing password of user - Update Database Table PHP/JAVA

Tags: java, php, android, sql-update

I have been trying to make a 'change password' function by myself. Meaning when a user wants to change his password, a dialog will pop up and it shows three fields: Old Password, New  Password and Confirm New Password. The old password is taken care of by using `SharedPreferences`.

`public void invokeChangePass` **WORKS.** So you do not have to look at that.

The problem is in the php file and the `private void updateDataBase` It will not change the password of the user in the database.

Everything aside from the php file and updateDatabase function works so do not worry about that.

**Useful notes:**

- I know it's vulnerable to mysql injection. Not my priority at the moment.
- `EmailKey` and `PassKey` are made in `SharedPreferences` when the user logs in.
- It is supposed to find the `EmailKey` in the database, in order to change the password of that user.
- It is as a while ago since I made this so it might have dumb mistakes or things I just forgot to add.

Thank you very much.

**JAVA FILE:**

```
 public class ChangePassDialog extends Activity {

    private EditText setOldPass;

    private EditText setNewPass;

    private EditText setNewPass2;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_changepass);

        setOldPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setOldPass);
        setNewPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setNewPass);
        setNewPass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setNewPass2);

    }

    public void invokeChangePass(View view) {
        String oldpass = setOldPass.getText().toString();
        String pass = setNewPass.getText().toString();
        String pass2 = setNewPass2.getText().toString();

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String passKey = sharedpreferences.getString("passKey", "DEFAULT");
        String name = sharedpreferences.getString("emailKey", "DEFAULT");
//        onPreExecute();

        if (oldpass.equals(passKey) && pass.length() >= 6 && pass.length() <= 30 && (pass2.length() >= 0 && (pass.equals(pass2)) && (!pass.equals(pass.toLowerCase()) &&
                !pass.equals(pass.toUpperCase()) &&
                pass.matches(".*\\d+.*")))) {
            updateDatabase(pass, name);
            setNewPass2.requestFocus();
            setNewPass2.setError("TEST WORKING.");
        } else {
            errorTest(oldpass, pass, pass2);

        }
    }

    private void updateDatabase(String pass, String name) {
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String name = params[0];
                String pass = params[1];
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://calisapp.esy.es/changepass.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    InputStream entity = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(entity);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String bufferedStrChunk = null;
                    while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return "";
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                String s = result.trim();

                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ChangePassDialog.this, Settings.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(ChangePassDialog.this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }


                        //                loadingDialog.dismiss();

            }
            }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name,pass);
        }
```

**PHP FILE:**

```
<?php
define('HOST','X');
define('USER','X');
define('PASS','X');
define('DB','X');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];


 $sql = "UPDATE tbl_user SET password='$pass' WHERE username = '$name'";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
       echo 'success';
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: How are you going to stop random people connecting to this service to change people's passwords to something of their choosing? All they need to do is know someone's username.

Comment: Also, you are storing passwords in plain text - it is best not to do that. Use a strong hashing algorithm.

Comment: Logcat doesn't show error ? Error log on the server side ? Try `error_log($name)` and `error_log($pass)` and check the error log. See if the post coming through. And set the content type in your java `httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: Connecting to? You have to be logged in on the app and know your current password? For storing the passwords, I was going to do security later. One step at a time. First kind of wanting this working atleast.

Comment: "You have to be logged in on the app and know your current password" - heh, no. You can use any web browser with a form on your own web server (e.g. `http://localhost`).

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the heads up! I'll be looking into that later!

Answer (score 0):

First. I don't think it's a good idea to use `AsyncTask` for that, as it could cause some problems. This is discussed [here](http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/).

But well, that's not your priority nor your question, so let's get along.

Change this

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

for this

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
```

And change this

```
InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(entity);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String bufferedStrChunk = null;
while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
}
return stringBuilder.toString();
```

To this

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),"UTF-8");

return resp;
```

And try to change your php file to this

```
<?php
    define('HOST','X');
    define('USER','X');
    define('PASS','X');
    define('DB','X');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if (isset($name) && isset($pass)) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Error while connecting to database!');
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_user SET password='" .$pass ."' WHERE username ='" . $name . "'";

        $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

        if ($res) {
            echo "success";
        }

        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: What does this change? Used your code changes but it does the exact same. Anyhow, forgot to mention, when  I click on the submit password change button, it goes all the way to 'Registered successfully'. Makes me think there is something wrong with the php file?

Comment: I've simplified the code. Guess the problem wasn't there after all. Well, what does happen if you try to run that query directly to your database?

Comment: Oh thanks! I think I found the problem. I passed down the emailKey to the function (..Database) and referenced it as 'name'. Testing it now, I'll let you know

Comment: Now with your php changes it does not go to 'registered succesfully' at all. I'm so lost.

Comment: Aha! It means one of your POST variables are not defined. Make sure you're passing your parameters correctly to your method on Android. Use logcat for that, or debug it.

Comment: @Calis: also, you can test your API outside of an Android/emulator. Use curl or similar at the command line.

Comment: I have no idea where I am going with this. I'll try again tomorrow. Can't even look at the code straight anymore. It's just weird. The whole java thing that connects to php is basically a copy of my register class which works fine. I dont see, how there is something wrong in the java.. Well thanks guys, I'll be back in the morning.

Comment: I'll be here. Just tell me.